# How to post a message that includes text an image to a Facebook group (or multiple)?

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do it with Python and Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time

# Init the browser and access Facebook
service = Service(".\edgedriver_win32\msedgedriver.exe")

# This is to avoid some errors
options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-chrome-browser-cloud-management"])
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.managed_web_usb_allowed_for_urls": False})

# Create the driver
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service, options=options) 
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
assert "Facebook" in driver.title

# To avoid an obscured window that doesn't let the program to find the HTML elements
def delete_popup_window(driver):
    try:
        element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".__fb-light-mode.x1n2onr6.x1vjfegm")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].remove();", element)
    except:
        pass
    
# Login
email = driver.find_element(By.ID, "email")
password = driver.find_element(By.ID, "pass")
email.send_keys("xxxxx@xxxx.com")
password.send_keys("xxxxxxxxxxx")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(10)
delete_popup_window(driver)

# Define the message
message = "My message"
messageImage = "C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\..."
groups = ["https://www.facebook.com/groups/xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "https://www.facebook.com/groups/yyyyyyyyyyyyy"]


for url in groups:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)

    # Click the element that creates the publication
    delete_popup_window(driver)
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Escribe algo...']") 
    element.click()
    time.sleep(5)

    # Put the text
    texto = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@role='dialog']//div[@role='textbox']")
    texto.send_keys(message)

    # Put the image
    #imagen = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "composer_media[]")
    #imagen = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Foto/vídeo']")
    #imagen.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    imagen = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[accept='image/*,image/heif,image/heic,video/*,video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/x-matroska,.mkv'][class='x1s85apg'][multiple][type='file']")
    imagen.send_keys(messageImage)
    time.sleep(10)

    # Post the message
    post = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Publicar']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", post)
    #post.click()

# Close the browser
driver.close()
```

The problem is that after it has put the text of the message, then when it puts the image it does it in a different publication, so when it clicks the post button, it only publishes the text message, without the image.

(It's important to note that I am the owner of the groups, and I am using a Spanish version of Facebook).

I had tried other alternatives that are commented in the code above, like finding the button with which we can attach images or videos:

```
imagen = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Foto/vídeo']")
```

But clicking that button opens a box with the file explorer of the operating system, to which I can't pass the path of the image automatically, let alone hit the upload button.

The Selenium version is 4.11.2, and the Python version is 3.9.0.